# Command to copy currently selected text

Tags: clipboard

Is there a way to copy currently selected text into clipboard? I'm trying to make my eastystroke gesture more general than "Ctrl+C" since it doesn't work in every application - for example terminal.

I know I can select with mouse and then paste with middle button, but I want to have option to copy into second clipboard since I track its history in clipit and it won't change when I select something.

I also know that I can change keybindings in terminal but I prefer not to mess with my habits when it comes to "ctrl+c" and terminals.

Comment: middle mouse click is pretty easy if youre in the terminal already.  Ctrl+shift+C is also pretty easy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that using `xclip` (package `xclip`, not installed by default):

```
xclip -out -selection primary | xclip -in -selection clipboard
```

Comment: of course, that's it

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Ctrl + Shift + C
```

to copy in the terminal.

Comment: I assume OP knows that, he even mentions it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Install Diodon clipboard. It has this feature by default.

```
sudo apt-get install diodon
```